# How to express Task dependencies in sbt 13

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, task

I am trying to express dependencies between two tasks in sbt 13.5. What I want to do is execute TaskB before TaskA will be executed. So I am trying to force the two Tasks to execute sequentially instead of parallel. In other words TaskA should wait for TaskB to finish.

```
taskA := {
   println("executing TaskA")
}

taskB := {
   println("executing TaskB")
}

//execute TaskB before TaskA ??
```

I looked in the documentation but couldn't find the section that describes how to express dependencies between tasks. How can I force the two tasks to be executed sequentially?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom settings and tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html) describes this in detail.

If you have the control over `taskA`, then you can write like this:

```
taskA := {
  val _ = taskB.value
  println("executing TaskA")
}
```

If you don't have the control over `taskA`, then you could try [sequential tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html#Sequential+tasks).

Comment: But how to change an existing core task with a dependency on a new task? E.g. I have a new task creating some folders and I would like the 'compile in Compile' task to depend on this. Redefining 'compile in Compile' causes a cyclic reference error. Using "compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn createRepositoryFolders" seems to work, but then the 'createRepositoryFolders' task is not performed when running the 'test' or 'run' task. I assume those tasks depend on the compile task.

Comment: Hi Joost! Could you open a new question for this?

Comment: I create a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066524/how-to-extend-an-existing-sbt-task-with-a-custom-dependency)

Comment: Why is this not working for me (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872758/how-can-i-make-a-task-depend-on-another-task))?