# How to extend an existing sbt task with a custom dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt

How to change an existing core task with a dependency on a new task?

E.g. I have a new task creating some folders and I would like the 'compile in Compile' task to depend on this, so that all tasks which depend on compile, like test/package/run/etc, also create these folders.

Redefining 'compile in Compile'

```
compile in Compile := {
  createRepositoryFolder.value
  (compile in Compile).value
}
```

causes a cyclic reference error. Using

```
compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn createRepositoryFolders
```

seems to work, but it seems to create a new 'compile' task which is not run by tasks which depend on 'compile in Compile'; the 'createRepositoryFolders' task is not performed when running the 'test' or 'run' task.

Using 'inspect compile' does show the dependency on the 'createRepositoryFolders' task, but 'inspect test' does show the dependency on the 'compile' task, but not on the 'createRepositoryFolders' task.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with the `:=` operator you are assigning a new value to the task `compile in Compile`.

Since you refer to `compile in Compile` in the definition of `compile in Compile` that is why you have a cyclic dependency.

What you probably want is to append to a task rather than define it anew. There are a bunch of operators to append values to tasks such as +=, <+=, depending on the type of values you're assigning.

However, since you are creating resources, you probably want to add your task to the resourceManaged task, rather than directly to compile.

Assuming the task createRepositoryFolder returns a Seq[File] you could add the following to the projectSettings:

```
(resourceManged in Compile) += createRepositoryFolder.taskValue
```

There is more info in the sbt [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html#Generate+resources)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot apply this in my case. I need to create some folders for the application to be able to run. These folders are created in 'target' folder and are not packaged with the application. On a deploy environment, Ansible scripts create the required folders with the correct security settings. The application is not allowed to create these folders.
Since I do not produce a Seq[File], I cannot use the += operator (I think). The <+= operator I cannot find in the documentation.