# How can I make a task depend on another task?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm new to sbt and I try to create a script for either deploy my application or to deploy *and* run the application.

What already works for me is

```
sbt deploy
```

which will successfully deploy the final .jar file to the remove location.

However, I don't know how to make `deployAndRunTask` dependent on `deployTask`. I've tried several things but none of them worked so far.

My last hope was

```
deployAndRunTask := {
  val d = deployTask.value
}
```

However, this does not seem to work.

This is the script that I'm currently at but `sbt deploy-run` will only execute the `deployAndRunTask` task but not the `deyployTask`.

```
// DEPLOYMENT

val deployTask = TaskKey[Unit]("deploy", "Copies assembly jar to remote location")

deployTask <<= assembly map { (asm) =>
  val account = "user@example.com" 
  val local = asm.getPath
  val remote = account + ":" + "/home/user/" + asm.getName
  println(s"Copying: $local -> $account:$remote")
  Seq("scp", local, remote) !!
}

val deployAndRunTask = TaskKey[Unit]("deploy-run", "Deploy and run application.")

deployAndRunTask := {
  val d = deployTask.value
}

deployAndRunTask <<= assembly map { (asm) =>
  println(s"Running the script ..")
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define your task and then *redefine* it. So only the latter definition is taken into account. You cannot separate task definition and its dependency on another task. Also you're using a couple of outdated things in sbt:

- use `taskKey` macro and you don't need to think about task name, because it's the same as the key name:

  ```
  val deploy = taskKey[Unit]("Copies assembly jar to remote location")
  val deployAndRun = taskKey[Unit]("Deploy and run application.")
  ```

  Then you can refer to them as `deploy` and `deployAndRun` both in `build.sbt` and in the sbt shell
- replace `<<=` with `:=` and `keyname map { (keyvalue) => ... }` with just `keyname.value`. Things are more concise and easier to write.

You can read more about [Migrating from sbt 0.13.x](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html).

So here's your `deployAndRun` task definition with these changes:

```
deployAndRun := {
  val d = deploy.value
  val asm = assembly.value
  println(s"Running the script ..")
}
```

It's dependent both on `deploy` and `assembly` tasks and will run them both before doing anything else. You can also use `dependsOn`, but I think it's unnecessary here.

You may also be interested in looking into [Defining a sequential task with `Def.sequential`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Sequential-Task.html) and [Defining a dynamic task with `Def.taskDyn`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Dynamic-Task.html).